# PHP header() issue cannot output image

Tags: php

I have 3 files

1. **upload.html**           //It uploads image on server
2. **check_image.php**      //it decides whether to save or preview image with some filter if preview is required it calls filter.php
3. **filter.php**           //it creates some filter on image and returns to check_image.php           //later  calls "filter.php

I have issue with previewing filtered image output an image does not appear on screen.
when I try reload the image I get this message: 
The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors.
how can i solve this problem?
my filter.php code is:

```
<?php
. . .
if (isset($_GET['id']) && ctype_digit($_GET['id'])
    && file_exists($dir . '/' . $_GET['id'] . '.jpg')
) {
    $image=imagecreatefromjpeg($dir . '/' . $_GET['id'] . '.jpg');
} else {
    die('Invalid image specified!');
}
//apply the filter
$effect = (isset($_GET['e'])) ? $_GET['e'] : -1;
switch($effect) {
    case IMG_FILTER_NEGATE:
    . . .
}

//show the image

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image, '', 100);
?>
```

i think this problem due to header() function please help

Comment: How does the returned file look? Use a hexeditor to see if it's a valid JPEG, or if prefaced by unexpected output.

Comment: just comment the `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');` line and check what you are getting. if there are any errors you can see it in the browser with the image header gone

Answer (score 0):

You do have a slight typo with the header; change it to:

```
header("Content-Type:image/jpeg"); //note the no space after the colon.
header("Cache-Control:max-age=17280000, public"); //so as to enable caching - in most cases you do want this.
```

Also make sure that you do not have any output before the header() or it will fail.

(but without the full code I of course can't test it - I know the code I just supplied works in my use cases.)
HTH

Comment: `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');` is valid. Reference PHP Manual  http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: hmm well it gave me errors with a space once (which was fixed with no other changes than removing the space - at least git didn't show any other changes)

Comment: but really thinking more I'm suspecting output before header - such as a UTF Byte-Order Mark; make sure there isn't one.

Comment: most probably some warnings generated by php can be the reason.

Comment: I commented header and I get message:

Comment: is the same. as of returned file it is empty little rectangle, I tried  the view image command and then manually change effect'e=' number it my filter number I get via url, and I get this message: Warning: imagejpeg(): Filename cannot be empty

Comment: thank you guys I resolved It:
header('Content-type:image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image,NULL);
?>